# Probability theory with python: Mean, Standard devation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, probability

So I am a relative newbie to python and an absolute rookie to probability. I am learning probability theory by creating a simple program in python.

The program is trying to model data about animals in a zoo. We have 100 random animals varying in weight from 1kg to 6000kg.

With the data we have are there any interesting statistical insights we can gain from the data, that I am not currently doing? Can anyone recommend models that can be applied to the data?  Or different ways of plotting the data with different methods or models. 
Any links or an example which show how to plot different insights to the data would be greatly welcome. Also, any links to probability or statistics which can be applied to data.

**Generate random data**

```
def generateRandom():
   animal_weights = []

   animal_weights.append(random.sample(range(4000, 6001), 7))
   animal_weights.append(random.sample(range(2500, 4000), 13))
   animal_weights.append(random.sample(range(800, 2500), 20))
   animal_weights.append(random.sample(range(100, 800), 20))
   animal_weights.append(random.sample(range(25, 100), 20))
   animal_weights.append(random.sample(range(1, 25), 20))

#creates 1 single list
   flat_list_animals = [item for sublist in animal_weights for item in sublist]
   random.shuffle(flat_list_animals)

   return np.array(flat_list_animals)
```

**Then we get the mean of the data, the standard deviation and probability that if an animal was randomly selected from the list, it would be an elephant or very large animal.**

```
def do_stats(animal_list):
    animal_mean = np.mean(animal_list)
    print("Mean weight of animal list: ", animal_mean)

    stand_dev = np.std(animal_list, dtype=np.float64)
    print("Standard deviation of animal list: %.2f"%stand_dev)

    stan_error_mean = stand_dev / (math.sqrt(len(animal_list)))
    print("Standard error of the mean: %.2f"% stan_error_mean)

    prob_of_elephants = len(animal_list) / 7
    print("Probability of randomly selecting an elephant or large animal over 4000kg: %.2f"% prob_of_elephants)
```

**We then randomly select 20 elements from the list, 20 times, calculating each time the mean and standard deviation. We then calculate the average of the 20 sample means and standard deviation's.**

```
def calculate_random_means(animal_list) :
    random_means = []
    random_std_dev = []
    for i in range(20):
        index = np.random.choice(animal_list.shape[0], 20, replace=False) 
        #creates a random list of 20 
        random_list = animal_list[index]
        stand_dev = np.std(random_list, dtype=np.float64)
        random_std_dev.append(stand_dev)

        random_mean = np.mean(random_list)
        random_means.append(random_mean)
        print("Mean of the random sample of the list", random_mean)
    return random_means, random_std_dev

np_random_means, random_std_dev = np.array(calculate_random_means(animal_list))
average_random_mean = np.average(np_random_means)
print("\nAverage mean of 20 random samples: %.2f"% average_random_mean)

average_random_std = np.average(random_std_dev)
print("\nAverage standard devation of 20 random samples: %.2f"% average_random_std)
```

**Finally, we plot the mean and standard deviation plus the average mean and standard deviation.**

```
materials = ['Mean', 'Average Sample Mean']
x_pos = np.arange(len(materials))

CTEs = [animal_mean, average_random_mean]
error = [stand_dev, average_random_std]
numbers = [0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#align='center'
ax.bar(x_pos, CTEs, yerr=error, ecolor='black', capsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel('X')
ax.set_yticks(numbers)
ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(materials)
ax.set_title('Mean and stanard devation')
ax.yaxis.grid(True)

# Save the figure and show
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: As this is principally a question about statistics and probability, it's off topic for Stack Overflow. It would be better suited to https://maths.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/ It may be worth explaining in the question on those sites that `random.sample` samples from a uniform distribution.

Comment: Dunes Can explain a bit more what you mean by "that random.sample samples from a uniform distribution" I don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: It just means every value in the distribution has the same probability of being picked. Like when you roll a dice you are just as likely to get a 1 as a 6. But when you roll two dice together and add then you are much more likely to get a 7 than 2 or 12. Rolling two dice is an example of a normal distribution (a.k.a. Gaussian distribution). I don't now those sites well, and I wouldn't want to assume they are familiar with Python's random module (though they probably are).

Comment: @Dunes Two dice is actually a bunch of points on an upside down triangle.  With 3 it becomes a curve.  As `n` increases it will become more and more of the bell shape of a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is your data is 1-dimensional. All it consists of are the weights of 100 animals.

Usually in statistics, there is a target variable (what you're trying to explain or predict) and explanatory variables (variables that will help you explain or predict the target variable). For example, if you wanted to build a statistical model of the weight of each animal, and you also know (for example) the height and age of each animal, a simple statistical model could be like:

Weight = a + b * height + c * age. A statistical method (for example least squares, which you can wikipedia) will select numbers a, b, and c which will make the left hand side of the equation as close as possible to the right hand side of the equation. So the model might look like Weight = 10 + 5.6*height - 2.6*age (numbers of course entirely made up). This means, if you have some animal where it's height and age are known, you can use that equation to predict the animal's weight (and conclude, for example, there's a 95% chance that the weight of the animal is between 60kg and 90kg (again, numbers made up))

Since you only have 1 variable, all you really can do is plot a histogram, and calculate things like the average weight, standard deviation of the weight, lowest weight, highest weight, percentiles of the weight, etc. A histogram of the log weight might be clearer to visualise.

Also, the probability of an elephant (for example) is just the number of elephants in the sample divided by the total number of animals (which is really just middle school mathematics lol)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Is there any value in the average mean or average standard deviation and can they be used to plot insight into the data?

Comment: If chosen randomly, no. If calculated based on different types of animal (e.g. reptiles, mammals, ...), then probably. In that case, animal type will be your explanatory variable.